# How can I set a Chart ID for a Google Sheets chart when creating the chart with Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

I am trying to set a unique chart ID using google script so that I can know the id and use the ID to modify the chart as needed.

However, the setID() gives an error when building the chart.

As a secondary issue, I am unable to getChartId() in my script.

See code below.  I have commented my two attempts

```
function createChart3(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
.addRange(sheet.getRange('b7:b20'))
.addRange(sheet.getRange('h7:h20'))
.addRange(sheet.getRange('r7:r20'))
.addRange(sheet.getRange('f7:f20'))
.setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
.setNumHeaders(1)
.setOption('series', {
  0:{type: 'bars', color: 'blue', labelInLegend: 'BPM' },
  1:{type: 'line', color: 'orange',  targetAxisIndex:1, labelInLegend: 
  'Energy'}
  })

.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
.setOption('height', 380)
.setOption('width', 600)
.setOption('title', 'BPMs and Energy By Song and Bucket')
.setOption('titlePosition', 'center')
.setOption('vAxes', {0: {minValue:40, maxValue: 160}, 1:{minValue: .40, 
 maxValue: 1}})  

.setOption('Id', '555')  //******this does nothing **********
//  .setId('555')  //*****this throws an error: TypeError: Cannot find 
//function setId in object EmbeddedChartBuilder. *********
.build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

I expect the new chart to have an ID = 555 so that I can write another function to Modify this chart by 
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[555];

Comment: Any reason why it must be 555? It doesn't seem logical from an engineering point of view. If you can fire up an example that we can check it would be great. But the chart once created should have an ID that you can use.

Comment: You can't use index of charts array as a unique id `chart = sheet.getCharts()[555];` will fail, even if chart id is 555.

Comment: @max- no reason. just picked an ID that was unusual for the example.

Comment: @TheMaster If I understand you correctly, the .getCharts()[Iid} returns an index, not the chart ?  I am just starting to learn google script (and coding).  I also dont understand whey setId() doesn't work.  It gives me an error as shown above.

Comment: `getCharta()[idx]` will return the chart. But that `idx` is not the id you can set using `setId()`. The `idx` is just ordered from 0 to say, 5(if the number of charts in spreadsheet is 6). If you must know `setId()` failed because you setId is not a method in chartbuilder,but in the chart. I.e., You must setId() after `build()`ing the chart.

Comment: FYI- if I use getCharts()[0] I am able to get the chart and modify it.  The [0] is for the case where there is only 1 chart on the sheet.

Comment: After build.  OK, I can give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pull up the chart again, you have to use `sheet.getCharts()` and then search that array until you find the one you want based on your [options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-options).

```js
function getChart(key, value) {
  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getCharts();
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; ++i) {
    var options = charts[i].getOptions();
    if (options.get(key) === value) {
      return charts[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Even better is to add Array.prototype.find to your script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Comment: Thanks @dwmorrin   So a "key" could be the chart type (for example) or a series in the chart?  Are you aware of how to use the setID() function?  I would like to be able to set my own ID (upon which I could search, I suppose).

Comment: @SteveP `Chart.setId` is a deprecated method.  [See this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761404).  Your code works, as written, with my `getChart` function, i.e. `var chart = getChart("Id", "555")`